# popcorn.js: on mobile browser youtube "play" button does not appear

Tags: javascript, youtube, ipad-2, popcornjs

I've been using Popcorn.js with YouTube videos successfully for a while. Starting recently, **on a mobile browser** (in my case on iPad 2) the "Play" button doesn't appear as it did in the past. The video will start to load, you can see the title, but then instead of a prominent "Play" button you get a black screen with a miniscule white dot in the center. After checking the source code, it seems that the video inside the iFrame's video wrapper is picking up a CSS style that gives the video a height of 1px.

If you press that barely visible dot the video will play and the Popcorn code will execute fine. That is pretty much a deal-breaker. Maybe this is a YouTube thing and not a Popcorn.js thing, but I'm just looking for direction.

See this simple jsfiddle, based on one of the Popcorn.js examples, for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzhpa/1/

The code:

```
var pop = Popcorn.smart("#container", "http://youtu.be/vDvmsTECAk4");

pop.footnote({
    start: 1,
    end: 5,
    text: "Works with youtube!",
    target: "footnote-div"
});

pop.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the autoplay which breaks it on ipad.

In the

```
/popcorn-js/wrappers/youtube/popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement.js
```

in the `onPlayerReady` function (around line 108) some tricks are done for autoseek & mute for initial loading.
The `player.playVideo();` in that function breaks it for the iPad because the youtube API does not allow autoplay on iPad. It should always start with a user interaction

If you comment the `player.playVideo();` line it works (for me).

I'm not sure if this breaks other things yet. I will see if I can file an issue at popcorn about this.

Comment: sorry wessel, just saw this here. Thanks for the info. I've kind of given up trying to use popcorn in the mobile browsers--but I would certainly welcome any improvements we could get.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly set the "controls" param to 2 to benefit from the speed boost but in PopcornJS, it tends to cause problems. Try forcing your "controls" param to "1".

**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid&controls=1**